# F#: why using outer function version faster than pass function as argument

Tags: f#

Version (calc1) using direct outer function take about 1s.

But version (calc2) with pass function as parameter of function take about 2s, that is 2x slower. Why?

```
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Numerics

let width = 1920
let height = 1200
let xMin = -2.0
let xMax = 1.0
let yMin = -1.0
let yMax = 1.0
let scaleX x = float x * (xMax - xMin) / float width + xMin
let scaleY y = float y * (yMax - yMin) / float height - yMax

let fn (z:Complex) (c:Complex) = z * z + c

let calc1 width height =
    let iterFn z c =
        let rec iterFn' (z:Complex) c n =
            if z.Magnitude > 2.0 || n >= 255 then n
            else iterFn' (fn z c) c (n + 1)
        iterFn' z c 0

    Array.Parallel.init (width * height) (fun i ->
        let x, y = i % width, i / width
        let z, c = Complex.Zero, Complex(scaleX x, scaleY y)
        (x, y, iterFn z c)
    )

let calc2 width height fn =
    let iterFn z c =
        let rec iterFn' (z:Complex) c n =
            if z.Magnitude > 2.0 || n >= 255 then n
            else iterFn' (fn z c) c (n + 1)
        iterFn' z c 0

    Array.Parallel.init (width * height) (fun i ->
        let x, y = i % width, i / width
        let z, c = Complex.Zero, Complex(scaleX x, scaleY y)
        (x, y, iterFn z c)
    )
```

Execute in F# interactive get the following results:

```
> calc1 width height |> ignore
Real: 00:00:00.943, CPU: 00:00:03.046, GC gen0: 10, gen1: 8, gen2: 2
val it : unit = ()

> calc2 width height fn |> ignore
Real: 00:00:02.033, CPU: 00:00:07.484, GC gen0: 9, gen1: 8, gen2: 1
val it : unit = ()
```

F# 4.0.1, .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in the first case, the `fn` is inlined.

Passing it as a paramter prevents this optimisation from occuring, so it is slower

Comment: To add to John Palmer's response, you could easily test the hypothesis by adding the `inline` modifier to `fn`'s definition. If that was the problem, the slowdown should disappear.

Comment: @piaste Make `fn` inline doesn't affect performance. But performance increase if `calc2` make inline too.

Comment: FYI; if you analyze the JIT:ed code in Release mode one see that `calc1` call to `fn` is indeed inlined. For `calc2` the call to `fn` is a virtual dispatch (which is rather costly).